# JSON RPC ethereumjs.tx in browser

Tags: javascript

I am using the [ethereumjs](https://github.com/ethereumjs/browser-builds/commits/master) library in my project, but when I require(ethereumjs.tx) it gives the following error:

`Cannot find module 'ethereumjs-tx'`

Any idea why the module cannot be found?

Comment: Have you installed this module? Use `npm install ethereumjs-tx` and then you will be able to import the module.

Comment: yes i had install.
this is my script tag in html file `<script src="/home/browser-builds-master/dist/ethereumjs-tx/ethereumjs-tx-1.3.3.min.js"></script>`

and in js file:
var Transaction= require('ethereumjs-tx');
error:
ethereumjs-tx module not found

Comment: @TamirNahum waiting for ur reply

Comment: I can't find any good reason why is it happening.

Comment: @TamirNahum on node it is working properly.Butt in browser it give an error :(